# Suspend during upgrade to 14.04 caused CORRUPTION

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, upgrade, suspend

An accidental **suspend** when my laptop was being upgraded from 12.04 (64bit) -> 14.04 (64bit) has stopped the system from starting up. It gets to GRUB and runs through the startup procedure but stalls.

**What is the procedure of fixing the OS?**

- Data on the system needs to be intact.

Comment: Where is it getting stuck (precisely)? Have you tried the recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either a CD or a USB pen drive that has the version of Ubuntu you want to install/reinstall.

For a USB you can use this [website](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to format your usb and install a bootable version of ubuntu.

When this is done, restart the system, boot from usb and run through the system.

You can repair, format, install clean copy etc.